# Avatar in Gmail

Tags: gmail, profile-picture

I have two avatars in Gmail as you can see below:
[image]

I don't know why there are two avatars. I can change only the one in upper right corner. The one on the left has incorrect aspect ratio and I can't find the settings in Gmail to change it. I suppose it was uploaded by my employer.

I will be grateful for any advice how to change the left figure.

Comment: Is this in G Suite? In the regular consumer Gmail, at least, there is a "My Picture:" entry on the general tab in Settings. That picture is likely different from your account profile pic.

Comment: I am not an expert but I suppose there is a backend (G suite administration tool?) and probably I do not have access there to change it. One avatar (the left one) is probably set there. 

I have access only to the gmail->settings ->General ->My picture, where the right one can be edited and the right one is set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Google + account, this can have adverse effects. The image uploaded to your G+ profile can appear on some, but not all services where your image appears.

If you upload an image to G+, then it'll appear in services like Calendar or Drive. But you can change the image in the Gmail settings as well and have this effect.

I suggest going into Gmail settings, remove your image, then go to your G+ profile and upload a new image. Everything should straighten out in 24 hours.